# Smoke detector beeps even battery voltage seems good

Tags: batteries, smoke-sensor

One of the smoke detectors started beeping the other night.  So I replaced its battery and it stopped beeping.  Out of curiosity, I measured the voltage of the old battery.  It surprised me with a 9.40V.  I then measured the new battery I just put in the smoke detector, it is showing 9.37V.  This is really puzzling to me why the smoke detecter beeps with a 9.40V battery and doesn't beep with a 9.37V battery.

Comment: The open voltage of an unconnected battery doesn't tell you much; try measuring the battery voltage when current flows ie. it is in your smoke detector and the smole detector is switched on..

Comment: Put your old battery back in the smoke detector and measure the voltage.

Comment: I believe you guys are right on the voltage with load on.  The smoke detector battery compartment is semi-closed and it's not easy to do the measurement with battery on.

Comment: Note that, as the smoke detector ages, it could eventually beep with a brand-new battery. They seem to have a usable life of about 5-10 years, after which they must be replaced.

Answer (score 2):

That is a frequently asked question here: batteries that go empty still have close to nominal voltage when nothing (or just a voltmeter) is attached, but drop when an actual load is present.

You can see the difference if you connect a sensible resistor across the terminals in addition to the voltmeter, "sensible" being dependent on the battery.

For a 9V block, I'd probably use something around [500–1000 ohms](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9V+%2F+20+mA), which should draw between 10 and 20 mA from the battery, which is within its specs, but noticeable. The empty battery should show a lower voltage then.

Comment: That seems to make sense.  I'll try to get a 1000 ohms resistor and to test it out.

Comment: Use the smoke detector as the load.

Comment: @Transistor, I'd expect the smoke detector to pull only short bursts of power for a measurement, then go back to a sleep mode, so you wouldn't get a consistent reading there (and for most of the time, the reading would be as if unloaded).

Comment: A 9V block has 1300mAh, so at 10 mA, that would be 130 hours, so a bit more than five days -- so the smoke detector definitely doesn't pull that continuously.